# Query windows version including build number and revision?

Tags: windows, go, wmi, windows-server-2016

I need to get **full** windows version, i.e. **major**, **minor**, **build number** and **revison**, so for example: *10.0.22000.1455* using golang app.

I tried using wmi - Win32_OperatingSystem class. Problem with this one is that it does not include revision, so what I get is, for example: *10.0.22000*

Other way I tried was calling *ver* command and extracting version from the response, which works fine, but does not work for windows server 2016 and lower. Simmilar issue as above

Any ideas for solution/workaround?